# $response = $request->execute(); is not working properly

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to fetch friend list of user from facebook php sdk(v5.0.0). Currently I am not getting any result. On primary debugging I got it is executing the code till echo 'hi1' but code is not executing above that. I have done below imports :

```
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
```

Below is the code I am using.

```
$request = new Facebook\FacebookRequest(
$session,
'GET',
'/me/friends'
);
echo 'hi1';
$response = $request->execute();
echo 'hi2';
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
echo 'hi3';
```

Can you please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: What is `$session` value? You should initiate FacebookSession with your personal token first. Did you do that?

Comment: I have initiated $session = new FacebookSession($accessToken); but after that above code stopped working. I even didn't get output hi1.

Answer (score 0):

please check in **Facebook\FacebookRequest** class   **execute()** and **getGraphObject()** this two functions are availble or you misssed something or you made mistake to pass data into 
`$request = new Facebook\FacebookRequest(
$session,
'GET',
'/me/friends'
);`

class like this

Comment: You are right. Functions execute() and getGraphObject() are not present in Facebook\FacebookRequest. Do i need to manually add it? I have checked in (v4.0.0) also and that file also doesn't contain those functions.

Comment: you need to check documentation for this php facebook sdk and implement it on proper way . i am not sure but you will do google for how to  implement it exactly.